# How to anticipate a new React protocol to block Javascript URLs as a Security precaution

Tags: web3js, react, phishing

Many Web3 dapps have a feature where sending a blockchain transaction conveniently triggers a pop-up link where one can simply click and see that transaction on a blockchain explorer. For example, you send, and it brings up a link to something like this

[https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe22b7053...](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe22b70535edec31234ed80e0c4b1491bfe46c0689686437263ff3b568e4dd56b)

I have this, but I am being warned that "A future version of React will block javascript: URLs as a security precaution. Use event handlers instead if you can."

I understand phishing is a big problem, but I also find this feature helpful. What is the best strategy for handling this? I don't want to create something that will generate errors in some future React version.